# Beamer template Warsaw— LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}

Tags: beamer, lyx, beamerposter, lyx-layouts

I am using warsaw template in lyx. But I am getting error about Missing `\begin{document}`. This is the description of this error message
`\setbeamertemplate{section page}[default][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shad...`. additionally, on first slide these two lines of code are appearing

`[colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true`
`[colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true`
Anyone can help me? And I think due to this problem I am unable to change its aspect ratio.

This is the tex code;

```
\makeatletter
\def\input@path{{\string"E:/master/TTh/slides/\string"}}
\makeatother
\documentclass[10pt,english]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\ifx\hypersetup\undefined
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \hypersetup{unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=section,colorlinks=false,pdftitle={title},
 pdfauthor={name},
 pdfsubject={title},
 pdfkeywords={title}}
  }
\else
  \hypersetup{unicode=true,
 bookmarks=true,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true,bookmarksopenlevel=4,
 breaklinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0},pdfborderstyle={},backref=section,colorlinks=false,pdftitle={title},
 pdfauthor={name},
 pdfsubject={title},
 pdfkeywords={title}}
\fi

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Textclass specific LaTeX commands.
% this default might be overridden by plain title style
\newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}%
% (ERT) argument for the TOC
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
  \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
  \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
%\geometry{papersize={160mm,90mm}}
%\PassOptionsToPackage{landscape}{geometry}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
%\usetheme{Berlin}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit} %%self for aspect ratio
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter} %%%%self for aspect ratio

%\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\hypersetup{bookmarksdepth=4,bookmarksnumbered=true,bookmarksopen=true}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}
% or ...

\setbeamercovered{transparent}
% or whatever (possibly just delete it)

%\usepackage{palatino}%
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

%Set Presentation mode and colors
%--------------------------------------------------------
\mode<presentation> {
  \setbeamertemplate{background canvas}[vertical shading][bottom=white,top=white]
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  \usefonttheme[onlysmall]{structurebold}
%
 % default | professionalfonts | serif |
 %    structurebold | structureitalicserif |
 %    structuresmallcapsserif
}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}%remove navigation symbols

%Using packages
%--------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage{amsfonts}\usepackage{amsxtra}\usepackage{pgf}
%\usepackage{german} %%I changed it
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{units}
%\usepackage{multimedia}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{movie15}
\graphicspath{{./picture/}}
\include{defs}
\usepackage{animate}


%Begin of the document
%--------------------------------------------------------

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}[default][left] %%for setting frame titles to the left

%%to change font size
%\usepackage{scrextend}
%\changefontsizes{10pt}

\AtBeginDocument{
  \def\labelitemi{\(\rhd\)}
}

\makeatother

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=american]{english}
\begin{document}

\title[title]{title\\
}

\subtitle{\textcolor{green}{\small{}(Supervisors: }\linebreak{}
\textcolor{green}{\small{}\&}\linebreak{}
\textcolor{green}{\small{} Prof.)}\\
}

\author{name}

\institute{Department of Media\\
 Uni\\
City, \\
}

\date{}

\makebeamertitle

\AtBeginSection[]{%
  \frame<beamer>{ 
    \frametitle{Outline}   
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  }
}

%\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\section{Motivation}
\end{document}
```

This is the result I am getting,
[image: sample]

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Don't use `\include` in the preamble. The correct command there is `\input`. If I remove the `\include{defs}` (we don't have your local file) your document compiles without error with xelatex in a current texlive 2021. Side remark: movie15 is obsolete.

Comment: Hey I am compiling it in Lyx

Comment: @ulrike-fischer thanks for the helpful response. I am getting : aspect ratio but the problem I am getting is that if I comment this ```\include{defs}``` it is removing that white first slide but this line of code``` [colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true
[colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=true``` is showing under title.

Comment: Sorry but as you seem neither to know which engine you use or if your tex system is current or how to check your log-files it is quite difficult to help you. That is one of the problems of a system like lyx.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience as i am a beginner. I am using lyx 2.3 -- miktex 2.9

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error when working with overleaf. I solved it by adding a new file called "beamerinnerthemerounded.sty" to the project folder with the code mentioned in [this link](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/raw/59750976/).

Comment: Please do not post links to files, since these links may become invalid over time. Instead, post the relevant parts of the code directly in your answer.